# How to convert many lines of text to json array progmatically?

Tags: arrays, json

I have a file with over 3k plus lines that are group in lines of 3 that represent all the timezones from javascript `new Date()`. The file currently looks like this :

```
Hongkong
HKT
HKT

Pacific/Easter
EASST
EAST

Pacific/Norfolk
NFT
NFT
...
```

Is there a way I could convert this file into a json array like this?

```
var jsTimezone = [

{
"region": "Hongkong",
"timezone_1" :"HKT",
"timezone_2" : "HKT"

},

{
"region" : "Pacific/Easter",
"timezone_1" :"EASST",
"timezone_2" :"EAST"
},

...

]
```

Comment: Yes, you could.  What would that algorithm look like.  One trick is if this 4 line pattern is consistent, you can loop through each line with i.  Wouldn't i % 4 give you either [0, 1, 2, 3] which correspond to each position in the pattern.  Tell me how you could use that to parse the file.

Comment: @GantTheWanderer: Alright. Will post an answer as soon as I figured this out.